# Окно запроса пароля

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, аутентификация, gtk3

Есть приложение на Python 3, в нем для GUI Используется GTK 3.0, все бы ничего, но приложению нужен пароль администратора чтобы работать правильно. Я уже написал форму которая запрашивает код пользователя, но хотелось бы реализовать все это без костылей.

Первое изображение - как не надо это делать:

[image: Мой костыль]

а второе - как желательно это сделать:

[image: То как я себе вижу реализацию без костыля]

Посоветовали pkexec. Решение рабочее но не совсем понимаю как впихнуть его в скрипт на питоне. На данный момент реализовал через скрипт на баше, который делает вот так:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkexec env DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" XAUTHORITY="$XAUTHORITY" 'ПУТЬ К .py'
```

И теперь все выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но всё еще похоже на костыль =(

Comment: вы уверены, что требуется пароль «администратора» (кто это вообще такой?), а не текущего пользователя?

Comment: Конкретно gparted запускается от root с помощью pkexec, и сам gparted при этом НЕ знает пароль — пароль запрашивает сам pkexec и уже после этого запускает программу от рута

Comment: Спасибо, @andreymal , pkexec именно то что я искал, но я не совсем понимаю как его использовать в pyhton коде, чтобы мой скрипт запускался я сделал другой скрипт на bash и вписал туда pkexec env DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" XAUTHORITY="$XAUTHORITY" 'ПУТЬ К ПРОГРАММЕ', Но все равно выглядит как костыль

Comment: Для разрешения работы с GUI в PolKit есть специальная опция, можно посмотреть пример у того же gparted в файле `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.gnome.gparted.policy` и по аналогии написать свой policy-файл